# VB and SQL datetime

Tags: sql, sql-server, vb.net, sql-server-ce

How can I format a date in Visual Basic to be in sql 121 style (that is yyyy-mm-dd hh:mi:ss.mmm).

I realized that this format is not in the FormatDateTime list of objects.

I want to use this format for Reporting Services.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

```
date.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.fff")
```

[Custom Date and Time Format Strings](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4%28v=VS.100%29.aspx#Y0)

Answer (score 0):

Since this helped me, I thought I would add a bit.
If passed into a method as a string then:

```
Shared SomeFunction(ByRef sStartDate as String)
Dim StartTime As DateTime = DateTime.Parse(sStartDate)
command.Connection = connection
command.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure
command.CommandText = "SomeStoredProcedure"
command.Parameters.Add("@StartDateTime", SqlDbType.DateTime)
command.Parameters("@StartDateTime").Value = StartTime.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.fff")
```

Cheers!